# Conway's game of life board not properly updating

Tags: c++

Sorry again if I managed to mess something up. When you run the code, it is supposed to do the be Conway`s game of life. The first board works as it should, showing X`s and .`s but all the following frames are just .`s

I believe the issue will be in `nextL` but I'm not sure...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <unistd.h>

int C = 0, R = 0;

void initL(char L[22][22])
{
    for(C = 0; C < 22; C++)
        L[C][0] = '0';

    for(R = 0; R < 22; R++)
        L[0][R] = '0';

    for(C = 0; C < 22; C++)
        L[C][21] = '0';

    for(R = 0; R < 22; R++)
        L[21][R] = '0';


    for(C = 1; C < 21; C++)
        for(R = 1;R < 21; R++)
            L[C][R] = '.';

    for(C = 1; C < 21; C++)
        for(R = 1; R < 21; R++)
            L[C][R] = (rand() % 2) ? '.': 'x';
}

void printL(char L[22][22])
{
    int C, R;

    for(C = 1; C < 21; C++)
    {
        std::cout << "\n";
        for(R = 1; R < 21; R++)
            std::cout << " " << L[C][R];
    }

    std::cout << "\n\n";
}

void nextL(char L[22][22])
{
    for(C = 1; C < 21; C++)
    {
        for(R = 1; R < 21; R++)
        {
            int LiveCnt = 0;

            if(L[C - 1][R-1] == 'X')
                LiveCnt++;

            if(L[C - 1][R] == 'X')
                LiveCnt++;

            if(L[C - 1][R + 1] == 'X')
                LiveCnt++;

            if(L[C][R - 1] == 'X')
                LiveCnt++;

            if (L[C][R + 1] == 'X')
                LiveCnt++;

            if (L[C + 1][R - 1]=='X')
                LiveCnt++;

            if(L[C + 1][R + 1] == 'X')
                LiveCnt++;

            if(L[C + 1][R] == 'X')
                LiveCnt++;

            L[C][R] = '.';

            if(L[C][R] == 'X' && LiveCnt < 2) //rule 1
                L[C][R] = '.';
            else if(L[C][R] == 'X' && (LiveCnt == 2 || LiveCnt == 3)) //rule 2
                L[C][R] = 'X';
            else if(L[C][R] == 'X' && LiveCnt > 3 ) //rule 3
                L[C][R] = '.';
            else if(L[C][R] == '.' && LiveCnt == 3) //rule 4
                L[R][C]='.';
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    char L[22][22];
    int T;

    initL(L);
    for (T = 0; T < 4; T++)
    {
        printL(L);
        nextL(L);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is years later, 5 minutes ago I remembered I had an account on here.

The issue with the code here, that the last `if else` statement tries set `L[R][C]='.';` where the rest set `L[C][R]='.';` and it was causing the math to not work properly.

Answer (score 2):

Right, the issue is in `nextL`, actually in the line `L[C][R] = '.';` before application of the rules. This line unconditionally sets each cell to `.`. Remove it to get correct results.

The working code snippet with its console output may be checked in http://cpp.sh/2egdu.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem stems from the fact that you change the value of each cell as you run through the array. The problem with this is that you get innaccurate neighbor counts because the values of the cells are changing at the wrong time. You need to calculate what each cell will change to on the next frame and store that information in a temporary location and then after you calculate all of the new values for each cell, you need to then change all values to their new value.

Example:
Your Method:

```
001
100
110
```

If you applied your algorithm to the above grid, starting the top left corner, it would remain unchanged(correct). Moving left to right and then down, the second cell does not change(correct), the third cell dies (correctly), the fourth cell lives (correctly), the fifth cell is brought to life(incorrect) because the third cell died before the fifth cell could calculate it's neighbors.

You need to write an algorithm to calculate the number of each cells neighbors first without changing them, and then update the values once all neighbors are calculated.

Like so:

```
calcNeighbors(); //loop through and find the neighbors of each cell storing them in a temporary array or class
updateCells(); //use temporary neighbor array and current cell value to change cell values to the correct value for next iteration
```

Comment: Do you know, off the top of your head, why the board would output just square symbols?

Comment: If your character values are higher than alphanumerical characters it could create squares because your console doesnt know how to output the symbol.

Comment: @Tatoes Your code only ever sets `L[C][R]` to `'.'`. Follow its logic. It's first set to `'.'`, then there's a bunch of `if`s. The only one that can fire if it's a `'.'` (which it will be since you just set it to that) sets it to `'.'`!